# What is the correct way to render absolute URLs behind a reverse proxy?

Tags: http, http-headers, reverse-proxy

I have a web application running on a server (let's say on `localhost:8000`) behind a reverse proxy on that same server (on `myserver.example:80`). Because of the way the reverse proxy works, the application sees an incoming request targeted at `localhost:8000` and the framework I'm using therefore tries to generate absolute URLs that look like `localhost:8000/some/ressource` instead of `myserver.example/some/ressource`.

What would be "the correct way" of generating an absolute URL (namely, determining what hostname to use) from behind a proxy server like that? The specific proxy server, framework and language don't matter, I mean this more in an HTTP sense.

---

From my initial research:

- [RFC7230 explicitly says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4) that proxies MUST change the `Host` header when passing the request along to make it look like the request came from them, so it would look like using `Host` to determine what hostname to use for the URL, yet in most places where I have looked, the general advice seems to be to configure your reverse proxy to not change the `Host` header (counter to the spec) when passing the request along.
- [RFC7230 also says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.5) that "request URI reconstruction" should use the following fields in order to find what "authority component" to use, though that seems to also only apply from the point-of-view of the agent that emitted that request, such as the proxy:
- Fixed URI authority component from the server or outbound gateway config
- The authority component from the request's firsr line if it's a complete URI instead of a path
- The Host header if it's present and not empty
- The listening address or hostname, alongside with the incoming port number if it's not the default one for the protocol
- HTTP 1.0 didn't have a `Host` header at all, and that header was added for routing purposes, not for URL authority resolution.
- There are headers that are made specifically to let proxies to send the old value of `Host` after routing, such as [`Via`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.7.1), [`Forwarded`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239) and the unofficial [`X-Forwarded-Host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Host), which some servers and frameworks will check, but not all, and it's unclear which one should even take priority given how there's 3 of them.

EDIT: I also don't know whether HTTPS would work differently in that regard, given that the headers are part of the encrypted payload and [routing has to be performed another way because of this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066#section-3).

Answer (score 2):

In general I find it’s best to set the real host and port explicitly in the application rather than try to guess these from the incoming request.

So for example [Jira allows you to set the Base URL through which Jira will be accessed](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/configuring-the-base-url-802593107.html) (which may be different to the one that it is actually run as). This means you can have Jira running on port 8080 and have Apache or Nginx in front of it (on the same or even a different server) on port 80 and 443.

Comment: I guess that would save a lot of header parsing and guessing to simply get the URL authority from the config instead, and RFC7230 does say you should try using that sort of environment data instead if it's available. Though I would still like to know if there is a "proper" method for figuring this out from the headers if config data isn't an option.

Comment: I agree with this answer. The load balancer will set various extra HTTP headers which you can parse but in general it's a nightmare, and won't work with a different load balancer (AWS ELB and Apache mod_proxy set different headers for example; plus you probably still want to test your software locally without any load balancer). I wrote in more detail here: https://www.databasesandlife.com/absolute-links/